# swapping array indicy function with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, char, swap

After seeing this question [Swapping in a char * array[ ] leading to issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444578/swapping-in-a-char-array-leading-to-issues)

User Claudiu gave a solution to swap the position of a string in an array

```
 tmp = array[compare];
            array[compare] = array[index];
            array[index] = tmp;
```

However, i was wondering how to make that in a function by itself. using pointers, and I just can't understand the link between pointers and char arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function:

```
void swapArrayItems(char* array[], int index1, int index2)
{
   char* tmp = array[index1];
   array[index1] = array[index2];
   array[index2] = tmp;
}
```

And then use it as:

```
swapArrayItems(array, compare, index);
```

Comment: thank you very much, just one more tiny thing, what is the difference between having char* array[] and char *array in the argument?

Comment: `char* array[]` usually means an array of strings. `char* array` usually means an array of characters representing one string.